# Run a silverlight unit test inside of nunit-console.exe

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, nunit, ncover

What is the best way to do this?  I want to get this working with nCover.

Comment: Most of these will need to run through the Silverlight plugin, so it isn't an easy task :-(

Answer (score 0):

I made a run at this and came close... but in the end it didn't really work out for me.

The guy from Test Driven made a template for testing silverlight in nunit.  I upgraded this to Silverlight 4.0 then I ran nCover.

The proof of concept worked great... but when I tried it on our actual product things fell apart pretty quick.

Many of our unit tests reference AGcore and others referent GUI objects, which is why I think I kept getting some sort of cross threading error.

I read that SilverUnit may be able to do this sort of thing... but you have to pay 700+ dollars per developer.  I wish the guy who wrote that would consider selling it separately.

Oh well... someday maybe I'll see code coverage numbers... not today though :-)

Answer (score 0):

zachary,

Can you provide more detail on "the proof of concept worked great"? NCover is not able to profile Silverlight because it does not support the CLR.

Comment: The modified version of the nUnit dlls run on the CLR so as long as there was nothing referencing Silverlight core or there were not any controls then everything worked.